# Cheapest way to return if INSERTed new row

Tags: sqlite

Let's say that I insert a record:

```
INSERT INTO table (pet1, pet2) 
VALUES ('dog', 'cat') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE pet1='dog' AND pet2='cat);
```

What is the least expensive way to check if the statement actually affected a row?

Comment: That's not valid Sqlite-dialect SQL...

Comment: But you're looking for [`sqlite3_changes()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) or whatever it's called in your language's sqlite bindings if you're not using C.